# Addition of two integer in binary representation

Tags: matlab, vector, binary, sum, integer

I would like to implement code which will add two integers by their binary representation.

For instance:

```
a = [1 1 1 0];
```

and

```
b = [1 0 1 1];
```

So I implemented the following algorithm:

```
function s=add_binary(a,b)
  m=length(a);
  s=zeros(m+1,0);
  n=length(a);
  c=0;
  for ii=n:-1:1
    d=floor((a(ii)+b(ii)+c)/2);
    s(ii)=a(ii)+b(ii)+c-2*d;
    c=d;          
  end
  s(1)=c; 
end
```

However, it returns this as a result:

```
s=add_binary(a,b)

s =

     1     0     0     1
```

Here, there should be an additional `1` on the left, such that it would read:

```
1 1 0 0 1
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s = zeros(m+1, 1)`

Comment: yeah yeah, i saw it, it was typo, but still it has some flaws

Comment: `str2double(num2cell(dec2bin(bin2dec(num2str(a))+bin2dec(num2str(b)))))`

Comment: i also solved it, i posted it as an answer

Comment: What is the largest size (in number of bits) that either input could have? What is the largest output size? When we need more bits in the output than in the input (as in your example), should we always add another bit, or would it "overflow" at a certain point and just stay the same size?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're dealing with binary numbers, why not use [logical operators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html)?

```
function s = add_binary(a, b)
  a = [0 a];
  b = [0 b];
  c = a&b;
  while any(c)
    b = xor(a, b);
    a = circshift(c, -1);
    c = a&b;
  end
  s = a+b;
end
```

And a test:

```
>> a = randi([0 1], [1 6])
a =
     0     1     0     1     0     1
>> b = randi([0 1], [1 6])
b =
     1     1     0     0     0     1
>> s = add_binary(a, b)
s =
     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution

```
function s=add_binary(a,b)
m=length(a);
s=zeros(m+1,1);
n=length(a);
c=0;
for ii=n:-1:1
    d=floor((a(ii)+b(ii)+c)/2);
   s(ii+1)=a(ii)+b(ii)+c-2*d;
   c=d;
 end
s(1)=c;
s=s';


end

>> s=add_binary(a,b)

s =

     1     1     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem was discussed in a 2011 question on [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1704-binary-addition-in-matlab). I'd like to mention 2 more solutions:

- If you have the Communications System Toolbox, you can use `bi2de` and `de2bi`:

  ```
  de2bi(bi2de(a,'left-msb') + bi2de(b,'left-msb'),'left-msb')
  ```
- If the amount of "digits" in the input is known (and reasonable), one solution could be to store all possible input combinations in some data-structure, which would facilitate rapid access. One such example is the [`MapN` class](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33068-a-multidimensional-map-class) (though it can just as easily be done with regular numeric arrays). I will provide a small example to show this idea (including a benchmark):

  ```
  function allResults = q43095156(allResults)
    if nargin == 0 
    % Let's store all combinations of 8 binary digits:
    in = uint8(0:255);
    out = uint16(in)+uint16(in.');
    outB = logical(de2bi(out(:),'left-msb'));
    [in1,in2] = meshgrid(in,in);
    allResults = MapN(...
       num2cell([num2cell(in1(:),2),num2cell(in2(:),2)],2),...
       num2cell(outB,2));
    end
    benchmark(allResults);
  end

  function benchmark(allResults)
    rng(43095156);
    a = logical(randi([0 1],10,8,'uint8'));
    b = logical(randi([0 1],10,8,'uint8'));
    % Test:
    R{5} = de2bi(bi2de(a,'left-msb') + bi2de(b,'left-msb'),'left-msb');
    R{4} = add_a_bunch_gnovice(a,b);
    R{3} = add_a_bunch_Sardar(a,b);
    R{2} = add_a_bunch_dato(a,b);
    R{1} = getFromMap(a, b, allResults);
    assert(isequal(R{:}));
    % Benchmark:
    a = logical(randi([0 1],1000,8,'uint8'));
    b = logical(randi([0 1],1000,8,'uint8'));
    fprintf(1,'\nSardar''s method:\t%f',timeit(@() add_a_bunch_Sardar(a, b) ));
    fprintf(1,'\nDev-iL''s method:\t%f',timeit(@() getFromMap(a, b, allResults) ));
    fprintf(1,'\ngnovice''s method:\t%f',timeit(@() add_a_bunch_gnovice(a, b) ));
    fprintf(1,'\ndato''s method:\t\t%f',timeit(@() add_a_bunch_dato(a, b) ));
    fprintf(1,'\nbi2de method:\t\t%f',timeit(@() de2bi(bi2de(a,'left-msb') + bi2de(b,'left-msb'),'left-msb')));
  end

  function out = getFromMap(a,b,map)
  out = cell2mat(values(map, num2cell([ num2cell(bi2de(a,'left-msb'),2),...
                                        num2cell(bi2de(b,'left-msb'),2)],2)));
  end

  function out = add_a_bunch_gnovice(a,b)
    out = zeros(size(a)+[0,1],'logical');
    for ind1 = 1:size(a,1)
      out(ind1,:) = add_binary_gnovice(a(ind1,:), b(ind1,:));
    end
  end


  function out = add_a_bunch_Sardar(a,b)
    out = zeros(size(a)+[0,1],'logical');
    for ind1 = 1:size(a,1)
      out(ind1,:) = add_binary_Sardar(a(ind1,:), b(ind1,:));
    end
  end

  function out = add_a_bunch_dato(a,b)
    out = zeros(size(a)+[0,1],'logical');
    for ind1 = 1:size(a,1)
      out(ind1,:) = add_binary_dato(a(ind1,:), b(ind1,:));
    end
  end

  function s = add_binary_gnovice(a, b)
    a = [0 a];
    b = [0 b];
    c = a&b;
    while any(c)
      b = xor(a, b);
      a = circshift(c, -1);
      c = a&b;
    end
    s = a+b;
  end

  function s = add_binary_Sardar(a,b)
    s = logical(str2double(num2cell(dec2bin(bin2dec(num2str(a)) +...
                                            bin2dec(num2str(b)), numel(a)+1))));
  end

  function s = add_binary_dato(a,b)
    m = length(a);
    s = zeros(m+1,1);
    n = length(a);
    c = 0;
    for ii = n:-1:1
      d = floor((a(ii)+b(ii)+c)/2);
      s(ii+1) = a(ii)+b(ii)+c-2*d;
      c = d;
    end
    s(1) = c;
    s = logical(s.');
  end
  ```

  And the results with my x64 MATLAB R2017a @ Win10 are:

  ```
  Sardar's method:    0.336414
  Dev-iL's method:    0.061656
  gnovice's method:   0.022031
  dato's method:      0.002123
  bi2de method:       0.000356
  ```

  So this should give us an idea which methods are faster (unless I messed the wrapper functions up greatly)...

  The advantage of the `MapN` method would be noticeable if the computation of the sum was some other, costlier operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`num2str`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) to convert `a` and `b` to strings and use [**`bin2dec`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html) to convert them to decimal. Then add them and convert the sum back to binary using [**`dec2bin`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html). Use [**`num2cell`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to split the string and finally use  [**`str2double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to get the desired result.

```
s=str2double(num2cell(dec2bin(bin2dec(num2str(a))+bin2dec(num2‌​str(b)))))

% Output for given a and b
%---------------------------
% s = 
%   1     1     0     0     1
```